# Making an ajax call in wordpress, undefined variable

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Im trying to open Wordpress posts in a modal popup by following this guide : https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/

However when I try I get an error saying : Uncaught ReferenceError: modalpost is not defined

I have this code in my functions file so far :

```
wp_localize_script( 'modal-post', 'modalpost', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'modal-post.php' )
));
```

And this code in my js file :

```
(function($) {
$(document).on( 'click', '.itemtoshow', function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: modalpost.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'modal-post'
    },
    success: function( result ) {
        alert( result );
    }
})
});
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong ?

Many thanks in advance,

Scott

Answer (score 2):

You have make some changes in your code like

```
wp_localize_script( 'modal_post', 'modalpost', array(
'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'modal-post.php' )
));
```

to

```
wp_localize_script( 'modal-post', 'modalpost', array(
 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

Then in your jQuery

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on( 'click', '.itemtoshow', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: modalpost.ajaxurl,
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        //action: 'modal-post' change function name here
        action: 'modal_post'
      },
     success: function( result ) {
     alert( result );
   }
 })
});
})(jQuery);
```

Now code response function in your plugin or functions.php file like

```
// Add hooks for handle ajax request
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_modal_post', 'model_post' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_modal_post', 'model_post' );

function model_post(){
  // Your modal code goes here
  // echo your modal code and then exit / die
  die();
}
```